# What's the crappy town means? or I got it wrong?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

I was watching a [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HVwUQ0Ok7Y&index=14&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBlmzzFcLgDhKTTfNLfX1IK). In the `2:20` minute, the author's friend calls him. he said:

> EvansMills is this crappy town next to me...

What does *'crappy town'* mean? Or did I hear it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly what the guy in the video said.

If you looked up the meaning of [crappy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crappy), you would know that the youtuber thought that the town of [Evans Mills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evans_Mills,_New_York), which happened to be a neighboring town, is not a nice place, according to him.

> **Crappy**: extremely bad, unpleasant, or inferior; lousy

**Update**

If you listen further to what he said, he says:

> "EvansMills is this crappy town next to me...and there is literally nothing there."

This only proves the fact that the youtuber, in fact, said '*crappy*' and nothing else.

Comment: I thought possible be Cape Town, the original is not.

Comment: Check the update.